# How to show progress dialog until the data loads in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to load the data from `Firestore` into `RecyclerView`. I would like to show progress dialog until the data loads completely. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code so far.

```
void loadPosts() {
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, DataViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataViewHolder dataViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Post post) {
            dataViewHolder.setData(post.getTitle(), post.getDescription());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_post, parent, false);
            return new DataViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before `.setQuery(query)` in your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` builder you can attach a listener to that query to know when it has completed in order to build the `RecyclerView`

**Example**

```
    progressDialog.show();
    Query query = db.collection("Users").child(my_user_id).addListenerForSingleValue(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Data has been fetched, hide progressDialog , check if data exists at the location with if(dataSnapshot.exists()) if you want to be sure theres something to fetch
        progressDialog.hide();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //The fetch failed, dismiss the dialog and show an error message
        progressDialog.hide();
      }
    });
```

Check the methods of [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)

Answer (score 1):

While Gastón's answer works, there is a slightly simpler way, that doesn't require an extra listener. The `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` has a method that signals when it has received a complete `QuerySnapshot`.

```
void loadPosts() {
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    progressDialog.show();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, DataViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            progressDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataViewHolder dataViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Post post) {
            dataViewHolder.setData(post.getTitle(), post.getDescription());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_post, parent, false);
            return new DataViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

Also see the FirebaseUI documentation on [`FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` data and error events](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#data-and-error-events).

Note that `onDataChanged` may be called multiple times, once initially and then each time when the data for `query` changes. So make sure that the code in there can handle being called multiple times. For example: if you destroy the progress dialog in `onDataChanged` instead of hiding it, you'll want to check for its existence too.