# Why the progressDialog is not dismiss when no data is present in firebase RealTime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

**Here is my code , my ProgressDialog is dismiss when data is present on firebase and fetch into UI,but this is not dismiss when no data present on firebase it still processing and when we tap on screen it goes , So how i can dismiss it?**

```
public void ShowData()//String data)
        {
           final ProgressDialog progressDialog =new ProgressDialog ( this );
            progressDialog.setMessage ( "Loading.." );
            progressDialog.show ();

        query1 = myRef.orderByChild ( "dateTime" ); // this is for Filter the data (The recently data you add is show on top of application)
        //  options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<modelClass> ().setQuery ( myRef,modelClass.class ).build ();//for retrive
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder < modelClass > ().setQuery ( query1 , modelClass.class ).build ();//for search and retrive
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < modelClass, MyVIewHolder > ( options ) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyVIewHolder holder , final int position , @NonNull modelClass model)  //for binding the View of recycler_view_item_layout
            {

           /* holder.college.setText ( model.getCollege () );
            holder.contact.setText ( model.getContact ()  );
            holder.time.setText ( model.getDateTime ());
            holder.food.setText ( model.getFood () );
            holder.name.setText ( model.getName () );*/



           progressDialog.dismiss ();
                    holder.setFoodPost ( model ); //for set all data to view



                //for set intent on Contact num View
                holder.contact.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String phoneNum = holder.contact.getText ().toString ();
                        Intent in = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_DIAL );
                        in.setData ( Uri.parse ( "tel:" + phoneNum ) );  // This ensures only Dial apps respond
                        if (in.resolveActivity ( getPackageManager () ) != null) {
                            startActivity ( in );

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this , "Failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                        }
                    }
                } );


                //for longPress on particular view(CardView)
                //for Delete the particular data when press long click on the View(CardView)
                holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener ( new View.OnLongClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        //for post_key we simply fetch that data postion which we want to delete
                        post_key = getRef ( position ).getKey ();
                        openDeleteWindow ();//this is a method for open the Delete Window
                        // Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this , "Press" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                        return true;
                    }
                } );
```

Comment: if you dont have data into not going into binding view try log s you can find your issue eassily

Answer (score 0):

The `onBindViewHolder` of a FirebaseUI adapter is called for each item that needs to be displayed in the view. If there's no data matching the reference/query that you show in the view, then the `onBindViewHolder` of your adapter will never be called.

So if you use `onBindViewHolder` to hide the `progressDialog`, that `progressDialog` will only be hidden if there *are* items. If there are no items, the `onBindViewHolder` won't be called and the `progressDialog` will remain visible.

To hide the `progressDialog` regardless of whether there are items, you'll want to override the `onDataChanged` method of the FirebaseUI adapter and hide it there:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < modelClass, MyVIewHolder > ( options ) {
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        progressDialog.hide();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyVIewHolder holder , final int position , @NonNull modelClass model) {
        ...
```

Since `onDataChanged` is called each time when an update has been completely received from Firebase, it will both be called when there *is* data and when there *isn't*.

Also see:

- [How to show progress dialog until the data loads in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475056/how-to-show-progress-dialog-until-the-data-loads-in-firestorerecycleradapter/60476508#60476508)